# Captions and labels for my tables, listings, images

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I'm writing my master thesis and I have a lot of short tables, listings, etc. in the text.

I would use figures for them like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
        ... my listing here ...
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{... caption ...}
    \label{... label ...}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        ... my table here ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{... caption ...}
    \label{... label ...}
\end{figure}
```

etc, but the fact that LaTeX moves them to another page (even though they are sometimes very short) makes the text hardly readable.

I would need LaTeX to keep them at exactly the same spot (if they fit there) or at the top of the next page (otherwise). It is my understanding that I should not use figures in this case. But, on the other hand, I would like to keep the captions, labels and numberings for them to still be able to address them.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would need LaTeX to keep them at exactly the same spot (if they fit there) or at the top of the next page (otherwise).

Given that you have many `float` objects, that they are usually quite small, and that they need to stay as close as possible to the respective callouts, you may want to load the `float` package and attach the `[H]` location specifier (instead of `[h!]`) to each `figure` or `table` environment for which the requirements you've described apply.

Answer (score 2):

Part of package `caption` is the macro

```
\captionof{environment}[short]{long caption}
```

For example an table you can left out environment `table` and use

```
\captionof{table}{long caption title}
```

Advantage: no floating, but you have to control whether there is enouph space for your table.  Same for figures.

Your `table` snippet:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    ... my table here ...
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{... caption ...} 
\label{tab:label}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `captionof` macro. When you say that one has to check manually whether there's enough space remaining on the page for the quasi-float, does this mean one has to insert `\clearpage` instructions by hand at times or else risk getting seriously overfull pages?

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. So, put differently, an overfull page is created if there isn't enough space to fit the figure/table?

Comment: Is there any advantage, then, of using the `\captionof` approach instead of the `[H]` approach of the `float` package (given that the latter won't create overfull pages)?